# ZXing QR code issue during Tab Switching in Android

Tags: android, multithreading, asynchronous, zxing, camera-view

I have an issue on ZXing QR code inside Tabs. I have 3 fragments one of which having ZXing QR implemented and i am replacing fragments on tabs switching.I have following code in my fragment class.**The main issue is when i switched tabs smoothly everything working fine. But when i switched tabs quickly again and again then CameraView became black and every Thread and AsychTask of Application stopped working**.This issue is destroying my whole application.

Here is code of Fragment's OnResume method. ScanningThread is a class extended with Thread and scannerView is a custom CameraView class.

```
    ScanningThread scanningThread = new ScanningThread();
    scanningThread.setScanListener(scanListener);
    scannerView.onResume();
    scannerView.setPreviewCallback(scanningThread);
    scanningThread.start();
```

Here is code of onPause method.

```
        this.scannerView.onPause();
        this.scanningThread.stopScanning();
```

Here is my setPreviewCallBack method of CameraView class:

```
  public void setPreviewCallback(final @NonNull PreviewCallback previewCallback) {
    enqueueTask(new PostInitializationTask<Void>() {
      @Override
      protected void onPostMain(Void avoid) {
        if (camera.isPresent()) {
          camera.get().setPreviewCallback(new Camera.PreviewCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
              if (!CameraView.this.camera.isPresent()) {
                return;
              }

              final int  rotation    = getCameraPictureOrientation();
              final Size previewSize = camera.getParameters().getPreviewSize();
              if (data != null) {
                previewCallback.onPreviewFrame(new PreviewFrame(data, previewSize.width, previewSize.height, rotation));
              }
            }
          });
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue resolved  by disabling tabs while thread is processing.

Comment: I think its a hack. I need a proper solution because i am working on a messaging application and due to this issue my messages stopped working once a thread got stuck.